# Was C# compiler written in C++?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, roslyn

Was C# compiler written in C++?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, but there are plans to write a C# compiler in C#, which I believe was discussed in [this podcast](http://deepfriedbytes.com/podcast/episode-27-present-and-future-of-the-csharp-language/).

Comment: Hm, on the surface it sounds silly, kind of like making dog food out of dog food.  I'm sure it has merit, though.

Comment: So what would be used to compile the compiler written in C#?  Talk about recursion!

Comment: @Josh: the previous version of the compiler. It's iterative, not recursive. They're not using the same version of the compiler to compile itself. Rather, they implement the next version of the compiler using the previous version.

Comment: Nothing unusual about that. A large fraction of "serious" languages are eventually bootstrapped to be self hosting.

Comment: @Kent: I think one of the tests for that compiler must be compiling itself! :)

Comment: Your objections are non-sense! C compilers nowadays can be perfectly written in C! C# compilers can be written in C#. The only thing that has to be C is the .NET runtime itself!
@Kent Boogaart: precisely. And since C# is backwards compatible(usually), it'd be perfectly fine to compile itself.

Comment: Seems pointless creating a C# compiler in C#, which is calling C++ anyway (the CLR)

Comment: @Hosam Actually, this could be the first step to self-awareness. Skynet, here we come!

Comment: @luiscubal, I think everyone's just having fun with the concept.

Comment: It is called Bootstrapping and it is fairly common to have a compiler written in the languages own language.  It is usually a matter of pride as well and marks a major milestone for the language.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)

Comment: @Simucal: the link isn't working because the closing parenthesis is not being included in the hyperlink. This one should work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29

Comment: I seem to recall that most parts of Delphi were written in, well, Delphi.

Comment: @Michael Meadows fish food is made from fish? :P so why not

Comment: To add a real world example that makes sense, Would it be wrong to use last years model of power screwdriver to assemble this years model?

Comment: Don't know why you'd want to rewrite it in C#. The point of languages such as C# is ease of development, not speed. With a compiler, speed is very much important and every second matters - especially on large projects.

Comment: This post is aging. Is C# compiler written in C# a reality now (.Net)?

Comment: For the purpose of history, the first c++ compiler was written in c++.

Answer (score 22):

Yes.

The Mono C# compiler is written in C#.

Comment: Was the compiler that compiles the mono C# compiler also written in C#?

Answer (score 19):

The .NET framework was written in Simple Managed C (SMC)

**History**

> During the development of the .NET Framework, the class libraries were originally written using a managed code compiler system called Simple Managed C (SMC).In January 1999, Anders Hejlsberg formed a team to build a new language at the time called Cool, which stood for "C-like Object Oriented Language".[16] Microsoft had considered keeping the name "Cool" as the final name of the language, but chose not to do so for trademark reasons. By the time the .NET project was publicly announced at the July 2000 Professional Developers Conference, the language had been renamed C#, and the class libraries and ASP.NET runtime had been ported to C#.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29

Comment: This answers a question, but not the OP's question.

Answer (score 9):

There is a new (as of late 2011) C# and VB compiler written by Microsoft called [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) which is written in C# and VB.NET respectively. Project page is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn). The Roslyn compiler is written as a library that exposes a rich public API. There is a news article [here](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/microsofts-roslyn-reinventing-the-compiler-we-know-it-176671) about it from InfoWorld.

UPDATE:
As of April 3, 2014, Roslyn is open source under the Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it was - as majority of CLR. If you want to see the internals of CLR and/or compilers I would strongly recommend Shared Source CLI from Microsoft (aka Rotor):

- [Microsoft Download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_Source_Common_Language_Infrastructure)
- [Shared Source Internals book](http://callvirt.net/blog/entry.aspx?entryid=b9a94d0c-761a-4d6b-bc2f-d6a5f8c1a4a7)

But, there is actually a compiler written in C#. I believe that [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is written that way. Download [Mono sources](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources-stable/) and find out for yourself.