# In what language is C# compiled

Tags: c#

Since I've been developing on c# this is a curiosity I have. Does anybody know that

Comment: C# is a language, so it is not complied, or even written(programmed). By the way, I think you ment in what language the C# compiler is written?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was C# compiler written in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631059/was-c-sharp-compiler-written-in-c)

Comment: The C# compiler prior to version 4 was written in C++. The next version will be written in C#. Anders Hejlsberg mentioned it at the last BUILD event I believe.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean? If you mean what is the compiler written in then I am unsure but ultimately C# and any of the .NET languages compile down to an Intermediate Language (IL), which provides a common language which then runs within the Common Language Runtime (CLR) virtual machine. The combination of IL and the CLR allows .NET languages to inter-operate seamlessly.

This is then compiled to byte code for the target machine.

If you use [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then you can inspect the IL code which C# etc. are compiled down into.

It is also possible to write your own IL code using the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) namespace and the [ILGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator.aspx) class.  It is useful for generating runtime proxies.

Comment: Info about the compiler implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631059/was-c-sharp-compiler-written-in-c

Comment: +1 Nice, I got my terms mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

CLR - Common language Runtime. That is then JIT compiled to the local machines byte code.

See here for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

Note that you can also compile C# with Mono which is an alternative to .NET . See here: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: Note you can turn javascript off, or hit escape while the page is loading to avoid the blackout.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Dessus - this blackout has been a real nuisance today...

Comment: CIL is really the link I meant to give. Its here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the .Net runtime and the C# compiler are written in C/C++

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631059/was-c-sharp-compiler-written-in-c

Comment: There is a .net version (unofficial) here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/02/06/368192.aspx . I have also heard from a conference that Microsoft research were writing a version of the compiler in C#. I can't find links for that tho.